# Android: control listview item from external button click

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a Next button and listview in my fragment.
when i click on the external "Next" i have to change background of the list item, 
second click it should go to next item in the list and change background.
and when i click next went it is in the last row it should come to first row item.

Below is my simple ArrayAdapter

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private List<String> list;
    private Context mContext;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        list = objects;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View mView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        return mView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is use `getChildAt()`
You should maintain current index
if user clicks on Next ->

```
private int index = 0;
public void nextButtonClicked(){
    updateViewAt(index,false)
    if(index==(listView.getCount()-1)){
      index = 0
    }else{
      index++
   }
    updateViewAt(index,true)
}

private void updateViewAt(int index,boolean isSelected){
    View v = listView.getChildAt(index - 
        listView.getFirstVisiblePosition());

    if(v == null)
       return;

    TextView textView= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
if(isSelected){
//TODO if view is selected functionality
}else{
//  TODO if view is NOT selected functionality
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. with few modification got my expected result.

Answer (score 0):

-maintain a pointer(starting with 0), which records the position of listview item for which the background is changed.

on every next click, if it is less than the lefth of list then increase it  with 1 and call notifydatasetchanged, else set it to 0 and call notifydataSetChanged.

-in the adapter class, in the getview, if the position is less than or equal to pointer, change the background else set to default.